# how can i add values from a loop in java

Tags: java, loops, numbers, concatenation

I've recently been given question for uni that is in regards to a credit card statement which says i have a string of numbers, then i convert these numbers to separate integers then i increment them by the power of 10 depending on their position in the string using horners method
i then have to add the values i get from the loop to make 1 whole integer. 
I Know this is an odd way to convert a string to an int but my assignment states that i have to use horners method to convert the string rather than use the inbuilt java classes/methods

My question is, How can i add the separate weighted numbers and concatenate them into one single number.

If it helps an example would be,

Given a card number 1234, the number is weighted according to its position and length so:

```
1 - 1000
2 - 200
3 - 30
4 - 4
```

Then these are added to create a whole number

1, 2, 3,4 ---> 1234

Here is my code thus far

```
public static long toInt(String digitString) {
    long answer = 0;
    long val = 0;
    String s = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < digitString.length(); j++) {
        val = digitString.charAt(j) - '0';
        val = (long) (val * Math.pow(10, (digitString.length() - 1) - j));
        System.out.println(val);

    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected? What happens if you feed it 1234?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably I am not following you, because this sounds too simple.
But to return a long (or integer) all you have to do is to sum these numbers:

```
public static long toLong(String digitString) {
    long answer = 0;
    long val = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < digitString.length(); j++) {
        val = digitString.charAt(j) - '0';
        val = (long) (val * Math.pow(10, (digitString.length() - 1) - j));
        answer += val; // here! :)
        //System.out.println(val);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Please note that this is not going to work with negative numbers, so here is a more complex version:

```
public static long toLong(String digitString) {
    long answer = 0;
    long val = 0;
    boolean negative = false;
    int j = 0;

    if (digitString.charAt(0) == '-') {
        negative = true;
        j = 1;
    } else if (digitString.charAt(0) == '+')
        j = 1;

    for (; j < digitString.length(); j++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(digitString.charAt(j)))
            throw new NumberFormatException(digitString);

        val = digitString.charAt(j) - '0';
        val = (long) (val * Math.pow(10, (digitString.length() - 1) - j));
        answer += val;
    }

    return negative ? -answer : answer;
}
```

This code will work with negative numbers and with weird numbers that start with a + sign as well. If there is any other character, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not Object-Oriented and really hard to read and understand. 
Basic, the problem is a mapping and really simple. 
If you are writing code in Java, better to use in OO way, though I don't like java very much.
Checkout my code

```
@Test
public void testCardScoreSystem() {
    Map<String, String> scoreMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    scoreMapping.put("1", "1000");
    scoreMapping.put("2", "200");
    scoreMapping.put("3", "30");
    scoreMapping.put("4", "4");

    String[] input = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

    long score = 0;
    for (String str : input) {
        String mappedValue = scoreMapping.get(str);

        if (mappedValue == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Hey dude, there is no such score mapping system! " + str);
        }

        score += Long.valueOf(mappedValue);
    }

    System.out.println(score);
}
```